# JSF 2 - show value of object, instead of key

Tags: java, jsf-2

I'm sitting at the moment on a legacy system. I've got some domain objects which are holding only the key of some entities, now I was wondering what would be the best approach to display the value of the entity instead of the given key.

Could this be done by a converter for the `<h:outputText />` tag?

E.g.

DomainObject

```
public class DomainObject {

    private String keyOfEntityA;

    // getter/setter

}
```

EntityA

```
public class EntityA {

private String key;
private String value;

// getter / setter

}
```

JSF

```
<h:outputText value="#{controller.domainObject.keyOfEntityA}" />
```

I don't want to show the key in this case, I want the object and the `value` property should be shown.

Is there an elegant way to achieve this or do I have to extend my DomainObject by a wrapper class, which provides the needed objects?

Comment: Could you post some relevant code to get a clearer idea what you're trying to do?

Comment: Just wondering, what kind of data do they hold? It look much like as if you're going to reinvent JSF builtin internationalization/localization.

Comment: No its not about internationalzation. The objects are holding product informations which are map by handwritten SQL statements... it's a mess

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either replace `EntityA` by a `Map<String, String>` so that you can use

```html
<h:outputText value="#{controller.map[controller.domainObject.key]}" />
```

or get hold of them all in a `Map<String, EntityA>` with `EntityA`'s key as map key so that you can do

```html
<h:outputText value="#{controller.entities[controller.domainObject.key].value}" />
```

I have the impression that `EntityA` should really have been a `Map<String, String>` from the beginning on or a `java.util.Properties` object if they hold applicationwide configuration settings, or perhaps a `ResourceBundle` with a bunch of properties files if they represent localized content.

Comment: Nice approach, I'll go this way. Thanks BalusC